# NextJS 14 revalidatePath for dynamic paths not working

Tags: next.js, caching, next.js14

I have the following directory structure:

```
src
  |__app
     |__layout.tsx
     |__page.tsx
     |__archive
        |__page.tsx
        |__[eventId]
           |__page.tsx
```

and the following serverless function

```
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function GET() {
  revalidatePath("/archive");
  revalidatePath("/archive/[eventId]");
  revalidatePath("/");

  return Response.json({ info: "finished running revalidatePath" });
}
```

**Problem**

`/` and `/archive` are getting revalidated, but not the dynamic `/archive/[eventId]`

**Note**: `export const dynamicParams = true` ([which fetches on demand if the route has not been generated](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#cross-route-segment-behavior)) works but I cannot use it as it fetches partial data from the DB (future events and eventIDs exist in the DB, but I'm filtering them by "ready to be used" to create the dynamic paths).

**What I've tried**

I tried many variations of `revalidatePath`, such as:
`revalidatePath("/archive/[eventId]", "page");`
`revalidatePath("/archive/[eventId]", "layout");`
`revalidatePath("/archive/[eventId]/page");`

but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Further info**

- `/archive` is a list of links to past events, each with an `eventId`. Clicking on a link takes the user to `/archive/<clicked eventId>`
- `/` displays the latest `eventId` that was added to the DB
- when a new event is added to the DB and I run the `GET()` function above, the new event is displayed in `/` and `/archive`, but clicking on it in `/archive` **correctly takes the user to `/archive/<clicked eventId>` but shows a `404` page (i.e.: the page has not been generated)**
- `/archive/[eventId]/page` is where my `generateStaticParams()` lives.
- the app is hosted in Vercel